# Getting duplicate data when using the select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting duplicate data when trying to use the select statements, I have 9 rooms but I'm getting around 50-70 rooms when trying to display them. Help please?

I'm trying to insert data and display it using the select statement.

```
create table gym (
    GymName VARCHAR(200) primary key,
    openTime time not null,
    closeTime time not null,
    Price decimal not null,
);

create table Spa (
    spaName VARCHAR(200) primary key,
    openTime  time not null,
    closeTime time not null,
    Price decimal not null,
);

create table customer (
    CustomerID int primary key,
    Firstname varchar(200) not null,
    LastName varchar(200) not null,
    DOB date not null check (DATEDIFF(year,DOB,getdate ()) > 18) ,
    Gender char(4) not null check(Gender ='M' or Gender = 'F'),
    Address varchar(200) not null default 'Jordan',
    spaName VARCHAR(200)  foreign key references Spa(spaName),
    GymName VARCHAR(200)  foreign key references gym(GymName),
);

Create table CustomerPhoNo (
    CustomerID int foreign key references customer(CustomerID),
    PhoneNo bigint not null,
);

create table Room (
    roomNo int primary key,
    Availability char(4) not null,
    NoOfBeds int not null,
    Rate int not null,
    CheckIn date,
    CheckOut date,
    Price Decimal not null,
    Breakfast char(4),
    CustomerID int foreign key references customer(CustomerID),
);

create table LocationOfRoom (
    roomNo int foreign key references Room(roomNo),
    seaview char(4),
    Location varchar(20) not null,
);

create table RoomType (
    roomNo int foreign key references Room(roomNo),
    familyRoom char(4),
    doubleRoom char(4),
    singleRoom char(4),
);

create table Gservice (
    GymName VARCHAR(200) foreign key references gym(GymName),
    Service VARCHAR(500) not null,
    MachineType VARCHAR(500) not null,
);

create table PaymentCard (
    CardID int primary key,
    issueDate date not null,
    Expirydate date not null,
    CustomerID int foreign key references customer(CustomerID),
);

insert into customer values (325,'Mohammad','Alasharan','06-04-1984','M','Amman', 'BeautySpa', 'StrongBody')
insert into customer values (348,'John','Shelby','10-18-1998','M','Birmingham', 'LushLife', 'SilverGym')
insert into customer values (495,'Thomas','Hoffman','04-26-1968','M','Johannesburg', 'RelaxationTherapy', 'SilverGym')
insert into customer values (194,'Anne','Frank','07-22-2001','F','Frankfurt', 'BeautySpa', 'StrongBody')
insert into customer values (628,'Katie','Swan','02-10-1997','F','New South Wales', 'LushLife', 'FitnessHeroes')
insert into customer values (246,'Mahmoud','Alkutaifan','04-21-1994','M','Amman', 'BeautySpa', 'FitnessHeroes')
insert into customer values (864,'Karl-Heinz','Rummenigge','09-25-1955','M','Lippstadt', 'RelaxationTherapy', 'FitnessHeroes')
insert into customer values (824,'Dennis','Law','09-21-1979','M','london', 'RelaxationTherapy', 'FitnessHeroes')
insert into customer values (463,'Carles','Puyol','06-17-1973','M','madrid', 'LushLife', 'FitnessHeroes')

insert into Room values (124,'yes','1','4',null,null,'30','yes',null)
insert into Room values (135,'no','2','5','05-06-2022','05-09-2022','55','yes',495)
insert into Room values (121,'yes','1','3',null,null,'40','yes',null)
insert into Room values (139,'no','3','4','05-10-2022','05-14-2022','110','no',194)
insert into Room values (131,'no','3','3','05-18-2022','05-22-2022','130','yes',348)
insert into Room values (136,'no','4','4','04-14-2022','04-24-2022','120','yes',194)
insert into Room values (179,'yes','4','5',null,null,'95','no',null)
insert into Room values (138,'no','3','3','04-02-2022','04-06-2022','75','no',246)
insert into Room values (146,'no','3','5','05-10-2022','05-14-2022','80','yes',864)

insert into LocationOfRoom values (124,'no','south')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (135,'yes','north')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (121,'yes','south')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (139,'no','north')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (131,'no','East')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (136,'yes','west')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (179,'no','south')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (138,'no','west')
insert into LocationOfRoom values (146,'yes','north')

insert into RoomType values (124,'no','no','yes')
insert into RoomType values (135,'no','yes','no')
insert into RoomType values (121,'yes','no','no')
insert into RoomType values (139,'no','no','yes')
insert into RoomType values (131,'no','no','yes')
insert into RoomType values (136,'no','no','yes')
insert into RoomType values (179,'no','no','yes')
insert into RoomType values (138,'no','yes','no')
insert into RoomType values (146,'no','no','yes')

-- display Total number of customers who booked a single room with sea view option
select count(Firstname)
from LocationOfRoom, customer, RoomType, Room
where seaview='yes' and singleRoom='yes'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: And please cut down your question to a [mre] with emphasis on minimal, we only need enough code to replicate the problem, we don't need everything you have done. The easier you make it for people to understand your question the faster they will anser.

Comment: @DaleK the code uses getdate(), therefore must be ms sql server. But you are right, the OP should have paid more attention to the tagging!

Comment: This seems to be your class assignment which you should be doing yourself by reading docs, taking help from numerous resources on internet while learning along the process instead of expecting tech communities to solve it for you. Just a hint for you to further study " you should use `joins` in select statement".

Comment: @PankajSanwal I have done that, and believe it or not, I'm top of my class (I know I know, I don't know how either) but anyway, I tried reading docs and getting help online. Thought Stack overflow could help, thank you for the hint tho, I haven't taken it in class so I don't think the professor is gonna allow me to use it.

Comment: @DaleK I have corrected them and made the post as minimal as possible, sorry for being such a big newbie, my bad!

Comment: You're selecting from multiple tables, but your query doesn't specify how these tables relate. So what you're essentially doing is a Cartesian product of all the records from all the tables. You need to learn about the `join` command

Comment: You want to keep 1 RDBMS - just not multiple

Comment: Don't use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: 1) I recommend using a consistent naming style with your upper and lower case. 2) You've provided more table definitions than is required for your query - remove any un-necessary fluff. 3) The `VALUES` construct is plural i.e. you can use it to capture multiple rows in one go, you don't need a separate `insert` statement for each row. 4) Best practice is to schema qualify every database object. 5) As already stated you need to investigate joins.

Comment: I got this error during insert:  sg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 6
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__customer__spaNam__0880433F". The conflict occurred in database "MainDb", table "dbo.Spa", column 'spaName'. The statement has been terminated.
Completion time: 2022-06-09T08:49:53.4764801+04:30

Answer (score 1):

Your FROM clause is missing the join condition for each table. In other words you are getting the cartesian product (every combination of rows) of the tables. Even distinct won't help (it will get the wrong answer). Use join conditions to link the keys of each table to each other. I'll leave this an exercise for you to try out, but this should be enough information to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the solution for your problem is that you need to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Firstname))
FROM LocationOfRoom, customer, RoomType, Room
WHERE seaview='yes' AND singleRoom='yes'
```

I have tested it and it retrieves 9 Rooms.

Comment: I have tried distinct, still displayed a large amount of duplicate data